# Excel-Formular - Get last workday

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formulas

In my sheet I want to get the last workday (So sundays and sutarday should be ignored) before the current day, if in A2 is "Select".

So for example if today is monday and in A2 is "Select" the formular should result in the friday of the previous week.

The formular I have only can get the last day but won´t ignore the weekends.

`=IF(A2="Select",TODAY()-1)`

Can you give me some advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you always want to get the workfday before the current day.

try the following:

`=IF(A2="Select";TODAY()-IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=2;WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1;1))`

Note: I´m working on a german client so im not sure about the semicolons, you might need to replace them with a commas

Comment: That works! But the formula Today() tends to change tomorrow with tomorrow's date which needs to be freezed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChandrasekarR Well of course, the `today` changes every day, if you want to use one specific day all the time just write the date into the formular instead of the `today`, or reference a cell in which you can put the desired date by hand.

Comment: `WORKDAY` function will give you previous working day more simply, e.g. `=WORKDAY(A1,-1)`